# How to use models in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting into CodeIgniter and trying to figure out the good architecture for my models. What kind of models would you create for the following simple example:

- list page of blog entries: shows part of the entry data, number of comments
- blog entry page: shows all the entry data, comment list (with part of the comment data)
- comment page: shows all the comment data

I'm trying to get this right so that it's simple and effective. I don't want to load too much information (from the db) on the pages where I don't need them.

E.g. should the same entry model handle both multiple entries as well as a single entry? And how should the comments be loaded? I only need the number of comments on the multiple entries (list) page but some of the comment data on the single entry page. How would you handle this?

Comment: *(official)* [Create a Blog in 20 Minutes](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're article_model model should handle all related queries and logic for any entry/article , however for comments related i would make a different model , let's call it comments_model .

Then you'll have a look at what data need to get displayed and build methods to retrive/handle that data in you're models .

Eg. For a blog entry page you'll need get_entry method in article_model , and get_article_comments in comments model , then for list page of blog you would need get_entryes and get_article_number_of_comments in comment model ....

---

Edit

For a page that list 20 blog entryes you'll have to make 1 query to list all blog entryes by calling article_model->get_entryes , and for displaing a 1 entry only you can call get_single_entry ( or get_entryes where you limit the result , or get_entry_by_uri , or get_entry_by_id ... ) . Then to get the number of comments for each entry you could make a get_multiple_nr_comment in the comment model where you pass entry ids and you're query would whave smth like "where comments.entry_id IN ( 1, 34, 55 ... )" there are a number of ways you can count multiple coments number in one query .

So you'll end up having 2 queries per page .

Comment: For me that doesn't sound too efficient.. If you suggest that "..model should handle all related queries and logic.." that would start generating a lot of db calls. E.g. a page that lists 20 blog entries. I would need to make 21 database calls. One for the list of entries and one for each entry to get the number of comments. Right?

Comment: @ATT: edited the answer with more info on how you can make you're pages do 2 queries only .

Comment: you could use a sql join to get the number of comments for each entry without using a separate query to get the number of comments...

Comment: @kevtrout: yes you could use join and have only one query per list , problem is what if at times you don't need the comments number ? you need to make aditional checks inside the method witch i don't realy like . Plus what i realy like 1 model per table , different tables different models this way i have everithing nice and separate , however at times when you have tons of queryes and you need to shorten page load , a join would be realy apreciated . Keeping everithing nice and separate means i can alter a table and edit one file alone to update with the changes .

Comment: true.  I agree on the one model per table.  I recently saved HOURS of work because of this.  The update was quick and easy.  I had to change the table name because of a conflict with a table created by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could create MY_Model, something like this:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    var $table  = '';//database table

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function get( $id = NULL ) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('id' => (int)$id), 1, 0);
        if ($query->num_rows() === 1) {
             return = $query->result();
        }
        return NULL;
}

    function get_one($id=NUNLL){}

    function update($id=NULL, $data=array()){}

    function delete($id=NULL){}

    etc...

}
```

And then in your **models per table** you can extend MY_Model, something like this:

```
class My_Table_model extends MY_Model {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table='my_table';
    }
}
```

You can then use methods from My_Model in your models.
In your controller you can have something like this:

```
class Table_Controller extends Front_Controller {

    function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('my_table_model');
    }

    function comments(){
        $this->my_table_model->get($get_id_somehow);
    }

}
```

If You want to override something you can  do it like this in your models that extends My_Model:

```
function my_method($id=NULL, $data=array()){
    return parent::my_method($id, $data);
}
```